# Neo4j forming json array

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I tried forming a json array in neo4j but it returned that my array cannot read the items from event. My code is as follows:

```
MERGE (n:item{id: event.id, description:[x:event.123,y:event.456,z:event.789]})
```

Thank you in advanced for the help!

Comment: Neo4j does not support JSON properties, if this is a spatial point, you could try saving it as a point format though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) will create the entire pattern if any part of it does not already exist, you should use it with a node pattern that contains only properties that uniquely identify the node. You can use `ON CREATE` afterwards to set any other properties  that need to be set if the node needs to be created.
2. A list (`[...]`) cannot contain property names. You proably want to use a map (`{a: ..., b: ...}`) instead.
3. Property names that are numeric (or contain special characters) cannot be referenced normally. You can use other syntaxes; for example `event['123']`

This might work better for tyou this:

```
...
MERGE (n:item {id: event.id})
ON CREATE SET n.description = {x:event['123'], y:event['456'], z:event['789']}
```